# Django admin CSRF 403 error

Tags: django, load-balancing, django-csrf

I have multiple django servers (API backend for mobile clients) running behind a load balancer. But when accessing django admin some times I'm getting 403 forbidden error. Is it related to csrf cookie ?

My load balancer setting is,

Session Stickiness   - None

Algorithm - Roundrobin

Comment: can you teach me how you are doing this, please 

Comment: You need to either turn on session stickness or turn off CSRF.

Comment: hi there, did you end up solving this? i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't imaging any situation when it's possible until you do all job in one browser tab. When you request form (with GET-request) you generate csrf cookie (if it doesn't exist yet) and generate `csrfmiddlewaretoken` for this cookie, in response you get both csrf token and cookie value in consistent state. On POST-request your browser send them both and compare on server side. So, this behavior shouldn't depends on backend. But you always can test your assumption with logger. From the documentation:

> CSRF failures are logged as warnings to the django.security.csrf
> logger.
>
> Changed in Django 1.11:
>
> In older versions, CSRF failures are logged to the django.request logger.

Comment: That's the whole point of CSRF protection that it depends on a backend. It compares the token from client cookie with the reference value stored in a session variable on that specific backend. Send that request to a different backend and it is supposed to fail.

Comment: I agree if you use Django 1.11 with `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS=True`. In other cases no matter what backend generates csrfmiddlewaretoken for you since it only depends on sent cookie value. Of course, I assume that all backends have the same source code.